# Summing a tuple-of-tuples and a nested dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, casting, tuples

I have data that can be represented in two different forms (for historical reasons that I won't go into). The first is a `tuple` of `tuple`s:

```
t = (('a', 'x', 3), 
('a', 'f', 1), 
('b', 'r', 23), 
('b', 'e', 3))
```

And the second as a `dict` of `dict`s:

```
d = {'a' : {'x': 45, 'f' : 4},
     'b' : {'r' : 34, 'e' : 45}}
```

Same data, different representation. I now need to end up with a combination of the two (and must maintain the tuple-of-tuples form rather than the nested dict form), with the values **summed**. i.e.

```
(('a', 'x', 48), 
('a', 'f', 5), 
('b', 'r', 57), 
('b', 'e', 48))
```

It seems this is a two-step process (convert the nested dict to a tuple of tuples, then sum the corresponding tuples within each tuple). I'm struggling to get past the first part, I am missing two tuples (and I don't like how I have hardcoded the indexing either):

```
In [1025]: def f(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        yield (k, d[k].keys()[0], d[k].values()[0])
   ......:         

In [1026]: for i in f(d):

    print i
   ......:     
('a', 'x', 45)
('b', 'r', 34)
```

What is a better way?

Comment: are the tuples ordered?

Comment: For the individual tuples within the surrounding tuple, yes order is important. At least, it's been made important by the fact that elsewhere in my code, I've hardcoded based on the position of elements in the tuples, which probably wasn't the best approach to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression within `tuple()`, by looping over your tuples and summing the third item with it's relative value in dictionary:

```
>>> tuple((i, j, k + d.get(i, {}).get(j, 0)) for i, j, k in t)
(('a', 'x', 48),
 ('a', 'f', 5),
 ('b', 'r', 57),
 ('b', 'e', 48))
```

Note that the advantage of using `dict.get()` method is that it returns 0 if the key doesn't exist in dictionary.

Note that if it doesn't make any difference for you to have a list of tuples or tuple of tuples, you can use a list comprehension instead of a generator expression. because list comprehension is more optimized in terms of runtime as it doesn't need to call extra methods like `next()` in a generator function in order to retrieve the items.

Comment: Curious to know why you changed your answer from your original list comprehension approach?

Comment: @Pyderman Because you want the tuple of tuple. If it doesn't make any difference for you, as a matter of fact the list comprehension approach is more optimized since it doesn't need to call extra methods like `next()` in a generator function in order to retrieve the items.

Comment: I see, yes it's the tuple that is needed. I am familiar with the `d.get()` method of avoiding a `KeyError`, but I hadn't even considered it (missing keys are indeed a real possibility in my full data set). Thanks.

Comment: And I never would have thought of chaining two `dict.get()` calls together. I would have ended up with multiple `for` loops getting me nowhere fast.

Comment: @Pyderman Yes, that's because `get` returns the item and you can call another method of the returns object, and that's why I used an empty dictionary as the default object of first `get()`. It preserves the code of raising attribute error if the first get return None.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension converted to a tuple provided you are sure that all your tuple and dicts contain exactly same elements (it works with current example):

```
tuple([(x, y, z + d[x][y]) for x, y, z in t ])
```

correctly gives:

```
(('a', 'x', 48), ('a', 'f', 5), ('b', 'r', 57), ('b', 'e', 48))
```

Comment: Nicely done. Yes my full data set is likely to have some non-overlapping elements, but your approach works nicely here for this reduced case. Thank you.